# Passing PDF unchanged through virtual printer

Tags: pdf

In Windows 10, I am receiving a PDF file from an external source through a running task tray program, which is automatically sending the PDF to my printer.

I would like to redirect that PDF to be saved on my hard drive. Sounds simple, so maybe I'm missing something. I only have the option to select the printer to which I send the file.

So far I have tried the following:

- setting up a virtual Generic/Text printer to save the output as a file, but the resulting output is a tiny file which shows a single UP arrow when opened in Notepad.
- tried the Microsoft Print to PDF virtual printer, but the output is a PDF of a PDF, which is subtly changed from the source (and does not convert to a text file, which is my ultimate goal post-saving).
- tried setting up a generic printer from the FILE: port, but it had the same UP arrow output.
- tried checking the "Print to File" option on the various attempts, but they result in the old, useless .PRN file format.

Any ideas on this (or an alternative approach) would be greatly appreciated! Unfortunately I have no other way to intercept the incoming file (that I can think of, but open to suggestions).

Comment: If you want the original (assuming the sender doesn't "print to" your program) PDF that the program receives, I don't see approach other than intercepting it before or "within" the program, as apparently the program itself initiates printing and will hence always process the file. If you cannot intercept the file before it, you will be looking for whether it caches what it receives somewhere, or seeing if you can use a hacked version of it (might be pretty feasible if you have access to source code)